# Open file which is stored in SQLite as blob

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

As the title, I create a ByteArray to store the file in blob like this:
byte[] red_buf = myCursor.getBlob(1);
But I don't know what's the next step to open the file :(

Comment: Have you considered saving your binary data as a file and then inserting the name of the file into your database?

Comment: My assignment is opening the file which has been stored in a sqlite file that had been created. So maybe I can't do any change to the database file :(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the byte array into a stream, most likely into memory. I'm not super familiar with android development and I can't tell quite which programming language you are using but that should point you down the right path.